# Loop through all elements with a specific style

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have a bunch of elements on the page with `background-color: #000685;` that have nothing in common (no common ids, classes, tag names etc,.).

Is there a way to loop through them all with JavaScript and change the background color value?

Comment: Nope, the only thing they have in common is having the same background color.

Comment: This question is not clear. If it's inline CSS style then you can... If it's external CSS, the you can't change the style, but you can add/remove a class to use the desired CSS... you really need to show us your code so we can help you.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini Sure you can. Inline style has higher precedence than stylesheet

Comment: @charlietfl: If you have external CSS, then you can't change the external CSS using using JavaScript... you either need to change the class or use inline CSS.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini It's trivial to set style inline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the elements have nothing in common, the best you can do is loop through every element on the page, get the background color for each one, and then perform checks. Like so:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  var cur = elements[i];
  if(cur.style.backgroundColor=="rgb(0, 6, 133)"){
    cur.style.backgroundColor="red";
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #000685;">I should be red</div>
<div>I should not be red.</div>
<div style="background-color: #000685;">I should be red</div>
<div style="background-color: #000685;">I should be red</div>
<div>I should not be red.</div>
<div>I should not be red.</div>
<p style="background-color: #000685;">I should be red</p>
<p>I should not be red.</p>
```

If the style isn't inline, use `getComputedStyle().getPropertyValue("background-color")`:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  var cur = elements[i];
  if(window.getComputedStyle(cur).getPropertyValue("background-color")=="rgb(0, 6, 133)"){
    cur.style.backgroundColor="red";
  }
}
```

```css
.one{
  background-color: #000685;
}
.two{
  background-color: #000685;
}
.three{
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">I should be red</div>
<div>I should not be red.</div>
<div class="two">I should be red</div>
<div class="one">I should be red</div>
<div class="three">I should not be red.</div>
<div>I should not be red.</div>
<p class="two">I should be red</p>
<p class="three">I should not be red.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some attribute to make the targeting proccess easier:

```
<span 
    style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" 
    background-color
>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</span>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
<span 
    style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" 
    background-color
>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</span>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<span 
    style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" 
    background-color
>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</span>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<p 
    style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" 
    background-color
>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</p>
<span 
    style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" 
    background-color
>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</span>
```

js:

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[background-color]'));
```

output:

```
// [object NodeList] (5)
["<span/>","<span/>","<span/>","<p/>","<span/>"]
```